# Different menu items for each row on a table

Tags: apple-watch, wkinterfacetable, wkinterfacemenu

I have a table on a WKInterfaceController. I'd like to have a set of menu items (WKInterfaceMenu) when the user force-touches on some of the rows, and a different set of items for the other rows. Also, I want to make it so that when the user force-touches on a row and then selects a menu item, I can trigger an action that is specific to the row and menu item selected by the user. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force Touch menus and other elements of watchOS are currently completely separated, so there isn't a possibility to realize such a thing. Also, Force Touch is not able to locate the position of the touch yet, it only says that the screen was force touched.

Take a cup of coffee, wait one or two years and then you will be able to do it for sure.

Comment: Thank you very much. Of course, as a developer, that wasn't really the answer I was looking for, but thanks for making it clear what I can and can't do yet.